# tf.Print() causing an error with gradients

Tags: tensorflow, gradient

I was trying to use [tf.Print](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#Print) debug statements to better understand the format of the reported gradients and variables from compute_gradients() but ran into an unexpected problem. The training routine and the debug routine (gvdebug) are as follows:

```py
def gvdebug(g, v):
    #g = tf.Print(g,[g],'G: ')
    #v = tf.Print(v,[v],'V: ')
    g2 = tf.zeros_like(g, dtype=tf.float32)
    v2 = tf.zeros_like(v, dtype=tf.float32)
    g2 = g
    v2 = v
    return g2,v2

# Define training operation
def training(loss, global_step, learning_rate=0.1):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
    gv2 = [gvdebug(gv[0], gv[1]) for gv in grads_and_vars]
    train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(gv2, global_step=global_step)
    return train_op
```

This code works fine (but doesn't print), but if I uncomment the two tf.Print lines in gvdebug() I get an error message from apply_gradients: 'TypeError: Variable must be a tf.Variable'. I thought tf.Print just passed through tensors -- what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Don't try to `tf.Print` `gv[1]` because it is a `tf.Variable`. It is like a pointer back to the variable which created the `gradient` in `gv[0]`.

**Further Information**

When you run `compute_gradients` it returns a list of [`gradients`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/411f57e291839094108afdaa9c43094f44979eaa/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py#L322) and their corresponding [`tf.Variable`s](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/411f57e291839094108afdaa9c43094f44979eaa/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py#L211).

Each element of `grads_and_vars` is a `Tensor` and a `tf.Variable`. It is important to note that it is **not** the value of the variable.

Your code works for me after removing `v = tf.Print(v,[v],'V: ')`